# Convert Pandas Dataframe from Column with List to Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column that has a list within it. I need to remove the list so that it is a typical series.

Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': [['try', 'go', 'spell'], ['you', 'should', 'to']], 'columnB': [['see', 'it', 'now'], ['why', 'not', 'yes']]})
```

[image]

Here is what I need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': (['try' " "'go' " " 'spell'], ['you' " "  'should' " "  'to']), 'columnB': (['see' " " 'it' " " 'now'], ['why' " "  'not' " "  'yes'])}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question you can use pandas [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
df.applymap(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

this will generate your output

[image]